# Multiple Dynamic Textbox Creation - ASP.NET, VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, dynamic-controls

I'm building a website where I want a user to be able to go to a form and on that form they can enter some text in a textbox and then click a submit button.  When they click the submit button I want a dynamic textbox to be created on a seperate form containing the text from the textbox on the previous form with the button.  I hope that makes sense : /

My questions are...is this even possible?  I was able to get the dynamic textbox (or label...whichever is preferred) created from a button click and show the user entered text but it was all within the same form.  I've read some forums that mentioning referencing the form.

Also what would be the "preferred" method of being able to create multiple dynamic controls (textboxes, labels, etc.) without using an array?  What I mean is...when the user clicks the button and the control is created on the other form I want it to stay there and then if another user does the same thing then the new dynamic control will be placed on top of the previously created one.

Right now I have some basic code creating a textbox but I don't think that will work since I won't exactly know the ID of it when it gets created so I was thinking of doing an array but I have since read that apparently newer versions of VB do not support arrays.

The 2 pages I'm referring to in my project are called Default.aspx and SubmitStory.aspx.

Any helpful information is greatly appreciated!  Thanks from this beginning programmer!

Comment: When you write "another form" do you mean a new browser window? I can imagine that being confusing for the user - they might close the original window, or forget that the second window is there after going back to the original window. Perhaps you could make the layout such that a panel holds the new textbox. Also, arrays are still supported in newer versions of VB, it's just that a List(Of <T>) is often a better way to hold a dynamically allocated number of items.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more specific.  The 2 forms I mentioned in my OP are both located within the same website application...no new browser windows.  They are links on my nav bar.  The Default.aspx page is basically my "home" page and the SubmitStory.aspx is a seperate form, or page, that the user can go to through the nav bar.

Comment: Some comments: (1) Have you created a system for saving the entered data, for example, a database? (2) Do you want other users to see updates as they are entered by other users? (3) I think that googling for "asp.net ajax jquery page updates" might lead you to some useful articles, but it is a lot to take in at one time. And hopefully someone else can chime in with something a bit more specific.

Comment: Yes I have a database set up that the users will log in to.  All that is already set up.  I do want to keep the dynamic controls up when another one is created so the users are able to read what the other users post.  Sort of like a comments section but instead of commenting on stories the users will just be able to read what people are writing and submitting.